# Why is sage not cooperating with urxvt?

Tags: terminal-emulator, rxvt

I am having problem getting the computer algebra system `sage` to cooperate with my terminal `rxvt-unicode-256color`. For instance, issuing the `clear` command returns an error

```
sage: clear
'rxvt-unicode-256color': unknown terminal type
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Update: Editing my `.Xresources` file to change the value of `URxvt*termName` from `rxvt-unicode-256color` to `rxvt` fixes the problem, however now I don't have 256 color support in my terminal. I'm still looking for a solution to this problem that allows me to keep my 256 colors.

Comment: How is `TERM` set to `rxvt-unicode-256color`? Do other programs work with this value of `TERM`? Are you running `sage` over SSH?

Comment: @Gilles I'm running <code>sage</code> in my terminal emulator which is <code>rxvt-unicode-256color</code>. <code>sage</code> seems to be the only program that has trouble with my terminal emulator. Would changing the value of <code>TERM</code> help?

Comment: Try with `TERM=unicode-rxvt`; it might make sage work but with fewer colors. Usually you shouldn't set `TERM` manually, but setting values for 256-color support is an exception. What OS/distribution/version is this?

Comment: @Gilles I'm using XUbuntu and controlling the value of term with the line `URxvt*termName: rxvt-unicode-256color` in my `~/.Xresources` file. Actually, I just edited `~/.Xresources` to `URxvt*termName: rxvt` and `sage` seems to be running fine. I wonder if this will affect other programs though?

Comment: `URxvt*termName: rxvt-unicode-256color` should work in Ubuntu (at least on 14.04 and probably even on older versions). If sage has a problem with it, it would be due to some peculiarity of sage that I'm not familiar with, sorry. Removing the `URxvt*termName` line from `.Xresources` is an obvious workaround but you'd lose 256-color support. How did you install Sage? PPA?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04, the terminal description for `rxvt-unicode-256color` is part of the ncurses-term package, while that for `rxvt-unicode` is part of `ncurses-base`.

[`ncurses-base`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ncurses-base) is an essential package, while [`ncurses-term`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ncurses-term) is not.  You could solve your problem by installing `ncurses-term`.